# Question about Rudin's Theorem 8.22 proof (Stirling's formula) - part (a)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

During the proof of Theorem 8.22, the following function is defined:
\begin{equation}
\psi_x(s) = 
\begin{cases}
\exp\left[-s^2\cdot h\left(s \sqrt{2/x}\right)\right] ~~~~~~~~ (s>-\sqrt{x/2})\\
0~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(s \le -\sqrt{x/2})
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $h$ is a function defined by:
\begin{equation}
h(u) = \frac{2}{u^2}\left[u - \log(1+u)\right]
\end{equation}

The following statements are made about this function:
[image: statements]

---

How can I prove (a)?

Comment: Too many questions in one post. I think you should ask one question at a  time.

Comment: Ok, just fixed the question accordingly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for a): $\lim_{u \to 0} h(u) =\lim \frac {2(1-\frac 1 {1+u})} {2u}=1$ and this gives a) easily.